# How to get the variable names assigned to another variable?

Tags: r

the example code:

```
target = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3
now = target
```

I want to automatically get the variable name of `target` (which is target) by using the variable name of `now`(which is now)

the expected result:

```
paste0(***the thing I need***,".best")
"target.best"
```

***the thing I need*** should be **only related to** `now`(because I want to automatically run the code)

could anyone help me with this? thx :)

currently I am aware of that I can use function `deparse(substitute())` to get the name but Idk how to get the name `target` only by using the name `now`.

by using function `get()`, I can only get the value of target, not the name.

in my case, what variable `now` refers to is flexible, it can be `target1` or `target2` so on so on. what I want is to obtain what `now` refers to by not using the variable name `target1`/`target2`. For example, if `now = target2`, the expected answer should be able to obtain `"target2"` by only using variable name `now`, `target2` should not be included.

Answer (score 1):

Using only substitute() to declare the variable `now` works to achieve your preferred output. Let me know whether I misunderstood your question, though.

```
target = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3
now = substitute(target)

> paste0(now, '.best')
[1] "target.best"
```

You can access the actual value of `now` using `eval()`:

```
> eval(now)
Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3
```

Comment: it s kind of misunderstood XD. I will keep switching what now refer to in my code. for example, now can be target1, but also can be target2, I want to obtain these variable name automatically by keep using the variable name now.

Comment: for instance,when now = target1, the result I want is "target1.best", when now = target2, the result should change to "target2.best", but most importantly, the function I need should only contain the variable name now, target1/target2 should not be in the function.

Comment: Okay. It is fairly hard to grasp without seeing the bigger picture of your whole code. However, if you merely reassign `now` as the substitute() of whichever target(1, 2, etc) is applicable at the time, then eval(now) will always output its current state.

Comment: For example, when `now` equals `substitute(target1)` then `paste(now)` generates `target1`. When `now` equals `substitute(target2)` then `paste(now)` generates `target2`, and so on and so forth.

Comment: yes I know how eval() works, as what you mention above, eval(now) will output the value of target, what I want is: function(now) output "target", not the value but the name

Comment: Considering that `now` is already the `substitute` of `target`, printing `now` will generate `target`, not the formula. The formula is only printed if you execute `eval(now)`.

Comment: yes I understand, but what I want is the code can run automatically, so target1/target2 should not appear in the function I am asking for, or not you will need to change the variable names everytime.

Comment: target1/target2 are formulas, I have over 50 of these formulas, now is just a variable indicating those formulas, I have to use the formula name planty of times in my code, so I am thinking are there any automatically code that can help me finish the work by using only the variable name now, that can save me a lot of time.

Comment: @recon It seems like you need different approach to your problem. E.g. if you  put this formulas in named list then you could refrence them by name.